# Math for kids with Cuisenaire rods

Tags: big-list, education

I work with kids and i am searching some cool stuff to do with [*Cuisenaire rods*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuisenaire_rods). Thinking about an application i thought that i can show to my students what will be the sum of first $N\in\mathbb{N}$ numbers using the sticks. Anyone can give me more usage like this one?

Comment: How old are the kids?

Comment: I hope the kids get well and you will teach them a lot of awesome math...

Comment: You can use it for Towers of Hanoi, maybe show them some induction with the Towers of Hanoi. A google search will get you to the induction proof.

Comment: @MJD Ranging in age from 14 to 18 but also larger. I do repetitions to students with trouble in mathematics and physics